# CFML RegEx to remove javascript comments

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion, comments

I am looking to remove javascript comments from a string using coldfusion. I am currently using `reReplace(string, "(\/\*.*\*\/)|\s(\/\/.{1,}[\r\n])", "", "all")`.

This is a test string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// comment
var a=1; // another comment
/* try{if (...)}; */
var b=2;
</script>
src="//domain.com"
```

The *expected* result is (and what I get using `replace()` in javacript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=1; 
var b=2;
</script>
src="//domain.com"
```

Actual CFML results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
src="//domain.com"
```

Again, it works in javascript OK.

How to get this working in CFML?

---

UPDATE 1, more specific code in my app.
It's basically a minifier within app.cfc's OnRequest() function.

1. Get the page html
2. Remove both types of JS comments
3. Flatten \r\n to \r
4. Replace \n+\t to a space
5. Replace \t to a space
6. Replace double spaces with a single space
7. Replace double \r with a single \r
8. Replace comma+\r with a comma

   ```
   <!--- Define arguments. --->
   <cfargument
       name="TargetPage"
       type="string"
       required="true"
       />

   <cfheader name="content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <cfheader name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
   <cfheader name="window-target" value="_top" />
   <cfheader name="imagetoolbar" value="no" />
   <cfheader name="viewport" value="wwidth=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />

   <cfsavecontent variable="finalContent">
   <cfinclude template="#ARGUMENTS.TargetPage#" />
   </cfsavecontent>

   <cfset variables.regex = '(?:("\/\/[^"]*?")|\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/.*?\n)'>
   <!--- <cfset finalContent = reReplace(finalContent,variables.regex, "\1", "ALL")> --->
   <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent,  chr(13), chr(10), 'all')>
   <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent,  chr(10)&chr(9), ' ', 'all')>
   <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent,  chr(9), ' ', 'all')>
   <cfloop from="1" to="20" index="e">
       <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent, '  ', ' ', 'all')>
       <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent, chr(10)&chr(10), chr(10), 'all')>
   </cfloop>
   <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent,  ','&chr(10), ',', 'all')>
   <cfset finalContent = replace(finalContent,  chr(10), '', 'all')>

   <cfoutput>#finalContent#</cfoutput>

   <cfreturn />
   ```

And some true (but truncated) output to play with:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (...) {...;}} catch(e){};
//]]>
// comment
var a=1; // another comment
/* try{if (...)}; */
var b=2;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 unsavedChanges=0;
 tinymce.init({
     // GENERAL
     // PLUGINS
     // LINK
     link_list: "/pagesJSON.cfm", target_list: [
         {title: 'Same Window/Tab', value: '_self'}, {title: 'New Window/Tab', value: '_blank'}
     ],
     // FILE MANAGER
     external_filemanager_path: '/filemanager/',
     // IMAGE
     image_advtab: true
 });
 </script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A400%2C700%2C900&#038;ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all'/>
```

Comment: You have to extract JS from the html before you can remove comments.

Comment: sin - the string to search in will be a html page, mixed with inline js and css. Also, your sample does not match all text from `//` to the end of the line it is on.

Comment: I don't quite understand what _your sample_  means. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I don't need to get every comment. If I can just get out /* and // I'd be happy. So, just need to find // when there is a space, tab or return in front of it followed by it's text then a return. /* is easy.

Comment: When javascript runs it knows `// foo` is a comment. Are you saying that's not possible with cfml and regex? To keep urls safe, I just need a white space in front of //, and a return after the text. I might be naive, I am new to regex... that's why Im here =)

Comment: I am looking to remove the comments from js inside generated html output from coldfusion, before it is sent out from the server. This is of course before js runs on the client.

Comment: That's not helpful. I didn't ask what I should do instead making *this* work. I have comments in tinymce init()s that will remain.

Comment: Example: `var tt = " where does // this comment begin";` The point is it won't work this way. There are ways though to make it work. This isn't the way though. I can give you regex to help you but you know the implementation environment, I don't.

Comment: That's some poor js. I don't think it'll be an issue, I'm only minifying my own.

Comment: I don't think you can brush it away as _poor code_, stuff happens, that's where bugs come from.

Comment: Multiline comment regex part can be enhanced with `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` (the slashes around are no regex delimiters)

Comment: @Jules, Your solution was moved to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<!--- JS with comment --->
<cfsavecontent variable="variables.jsWithCommment">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // comment
    var a=1; // another comment
    /* try{if (...)}; */
    var b=2;
    </script>
    src="//domain.com"
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- Replace with first capture for each branch --->
<cfset variables.regex = '(?:("\/\/[^"]*?")|\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/.*?\n)'>
<cfset variables.jsWithoutComment = reReplace(variables.jsWithCommment, variables.regex, "\1", "ALL")>
```

**Regex:**

```
Branch 1: ("\/\/[^"]*?")  ==> Capture(to replace with same later i.e., \1) URL shorthand
Branch 2: \/\*.*?\*\/     ==> MultiLine Comment
Branch 3: \/\/.*?\n       ==> SingleLine Comment
```

Here is the [`TryCF`](http://trycf.com/gist/0c09ff9ee3d08314edd0d5ccb5c36894/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Comment: This works great in tryCF but in my app the `link` tags get broken. I'm going to amend my question with more specific code.

Comment: `\s(\/\/.*?\r\n)` works for the trailling singleLine comment!

Comment: Beginner - you got me on the right track to solving the problem for me. Thank you! `\/\*.*?\*\/|\s(\/\/.*?\r\n)` is the final answer.

Comment: @Jules What is the issue with `\/\/.*?\n` for singleLine comment?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In ColdFusion, [A period matches any character, including newline](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7fef).

Comment: Beginner, `\/\/.*?\n`wipes out links with no protocol, ex `src="//`. So I need to look for white space in front of // - return, tab, or space.

Comment: In my environment `link`s were being broken when I ran your exact example. `<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A400%2C700%2C900&#038;ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)...` became: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='https:
 <script type="text/javascript">
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)...`

Comment: it looks like that only works on https://. What about http://, or no protocol at all, or no quotes at all (pre-minified html)? The easiest thing to do is simply look for white space before //.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The correct reReplace is:

```
reReplace(finalContent, '\/\*.*?\*\/|\s(\/\/.*?\r\n)', "", "ALL")
```

Makes the below output. Still needs some cleaning but links and js functions don't break!

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       try{if (...) {...;}} catch(e){};
          var a=1;    
    var b=2;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     unsavedChanges=0;
     tinymce.init({
                                 link_list: "/pagesJSON.cfm", target_list: [
             {title: 'Same Window/Tab', value: '_self'}, {title: 'New Window/Tab', value: '_blank'}
         ],
                 external_filemanager_path: '/filemanager/',
                 image_advtab: true
     });
     </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A400%2C700%2C900&#038;ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression pattern which you are currently trying seems to be incorrect, (I have tried validating it with the "Online RegEx Tester" and confirmed).

You need to rewrite it as,

`\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^:"]|^)\/\/.*$`

Here is the screenshot from, https://regex101.com/#javascript (Where I had tested the above pattern)

[image]

Try using the `\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^:"]|^)\/\/.*$` in your `reReplace` function which will workout for you.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: You wouldn't want it to match `src="//domain.com"` because that isn't a comment, it's shorthand for the URL, which omits the protocol.

Comment: @wcarroll Thanks for pointing it out. I have altered my pattern to ignore quotes now.